# React Native how to fetch data with API URL

Tags: react-native, axios, zomato-api

I am trying to retrieve data from the Zomato API (https://developers.zomato.com/documentation) and I am attempting to retrieve restaurants from a selected category. This is my first time using APIs so if anybody can walk me through what I am not understanding, or if there is a mistake in my code I would really appreciate it.

Here is my relevant code:

HomeScreen.js

```
async componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({
    data: await apiCall('')
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        style={{ marginBottom: 80 }}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={({ item }) =>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('CategoryScreen', { category: item.categories.id })}>//the user will tap on the category and the CategoryID will be moved to the next screen
            <Card style={styles.container}>
              <Text style={{ color: '#000', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.categories.name} </Text>
            </Card>
          </TouchableHighlight>}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
}
```

once the user taps on the category cell within the flat list the project should list out all the restaurants within that category in the next page

CategoryScreen.js

```
 async componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({
    data: await apiSearch('`{this.props.navigate.category}`')
  })
  console.log(await apiSearch)
}

render(){
  return (
    <FlatList
      style={{ marginBottom: 80 }}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={({ item }) =>
        <Card style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={{ color: '#000', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.restaurants.name} </Text>
        </Card>}
    />
  );
}
```

Here is the file in which I have all the API call functions

API.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const apiCall = async () => {
  return await axios.request({
    baseURL: "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/categories?city_id=New%20Jersey%20",
    headers: {
      'user-key': "a31bd76da32396a27b6906bf0ca707a2",
    },
    method: 'get'
  }).then(async (response) => {
    return response.data.categories
  }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

export const apiSearch = async (id) => {
  return await axios.request({
    baseURL: `https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?category=${id}`,
    headers: {
      'user-key': "a31bd76da32396a27b6906bf0ca707a2",
    },
    method: 'get'
  }).then(async (response) => {
    return response.data.restaurants
  }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

According to the Zomato API documentation says

> List of all restaurants categorized under a particular restaurant type can be obtained using /Search API with Category ID as inputs

each category ID is a specific number and goes at the end of the baseURL in the `apiSearch` const. So what I'm trying to do is add the category ID from the first page to the end of the URL of the second page because that's how I think the restaurants within each category will be displayed. However I'm starting to think that's not entirely correct. I am just genuinely confused about how to work with APIs

Comment: what is the problem you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing selected category id in HomeScreen.js, you can access that value from CategoryScreen.js as below,

```
this.props.navigation.navigation.state.params.category
```

Now you need pass that value to `https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search` as a Parameter

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let id = this.props.navigation.state.params.category
    let result;
    try {
      result = await axios.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?category=${id}`,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'user-key': "a31bd76da32396a27b6906bf0ca707a2",
        },
      })
    } catch (err) {
      err => console.log(err)
    }
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      data: result.data.restaurants
    })
  }
```

Finally you can show that data inside CategoryScreen.js

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {
          this.state.isLoading ?
            <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
              <ActivityIndicator />
            </View> :
            (
              this.state.data.length == 0 ?
                <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
                  <Text style={{ color: '#000', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>No restaurants from selected category</Text>
                </View> :
                <FlatList
                  style={{ marginBottom: 80 }}
                  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                  data={this.state.data}
                  renderItem={({ item }) =>
                    <Text style={{ color: '#000', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.restaurant.name} </Text>
                  }
                />
            )
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: lol it worked! I just forgot to import axios (dumb mistake) Thank you!

Comment: is there a place you recommend that is a good way for me to learn how to use axios and all these methods?

Comment: @CoolMAn I think it's better to check their official Github repo - https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 async componentDidMount(){
     let response = await apiSearch('`{this.props.navigate.category}`')
     console.log(response)
     this.setState({
       data: response
     }) 
 }
```